# Extract each xml node in separate txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a xml file like this:

```
<root>
    <article>
        <article_taxonomy></article_taxonomy>
        <article_place>Somewhere</article_place>
        <article_number>1</article_number>
        <article_date>2001</article_date>
        <article_body>Blah blah balh</article_body>
    </article>

    <article>
        <article_taxonomy></article_taxonomy>
        <article_place>Somewhere</article_place>
        <article_number>2</article_number>
        <article_date>2001</article_date>
        <article_body>Blah blah balh</article_body>
    </article>

    ...
    ...
    more nodes

</root>
```

What i am trying to do is to extract and write each node (from `<article> to </article>` tags) to a separate txt or xml file. I want to keep the tags also.

Is it possible to do it without regular expressions? Are there any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend using one of the XML modules, not regular expression. It gets the job done the correct way. BTW, your XML does not seem to have a root node to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `ElementTree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

def main():
    with open('data.xml') as f:
        et = ElementTree.parse(f)
        for article in et.findall('article'):
            xml_string = ElementTree.tostring(article)
            # Now you can write xml_string to a new file
            # Take care to name the files sequentially

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmlfile = minidom.parse('yourfile.xml')
#for example for 'article_body'
article_body = xmlfile.getElementsByTagName('article_body')
```

or

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlfile = ET.parse('yourfile.xml')
root_tag = xmlfile.getroot()
for each_article in root_tag.findall('article'):
   article_taxonomy = each_article.find('article_taxonomy').text
   article_place = each_article.find('article_place').text
   # etc etc
```